# How do I left, center and right align within formulas

Tags: formatting, align

I am struggling getting the alignment in a formula the way I want. The following snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \[ %
     \begin{aligned}
        l \cdot e \cdot f \cdot & = & c+e+n+t+e+r & + 2\pi     \\
        foo                     & = & bar         & +    1     
     \end{aligned}
 \]
\end{document}
```

produces this output:
[image: produces]

Yet, I'd like the first column to be left aligned, the third column to be center-aligned and the last column to be right aligned.

Besides, I don't really understand why tex chooses the first column to be right aligned and the last column to be left aligned.

Comment: Then use an `array`.

Comment: re choosing the first column to be left-aligned and the "last" column to be right-aligned, the usual content of this sort of alignment is equations or inequality statements, or groups of such statements mutually aligned.  please refer to the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`).  in any event, you shouldn't have an `&` after the `=` sign; that results in incorrect spacing.  the suggestion to use an `array` is appropriate for the use you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `array` environment, like this. (Edit: like Manuel suggested too.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\[ 
  \begin{array}{lcccr}
     \l \cdot e \cdot f \cdot t & = & c+e+n+t+e+r  & + & 2\pi     \\
     foo & = & bar & + & 1     
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the spacing here is not wonderful, although i don't fully understand what the op really wants.  decreasing the inter-column spacing would seem appropriate here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Since the OP wants the first column to be left-aligned and the last column to be right-aligned, we can reasonably deduce he doesn't mind big spacings…

Comment: big spacing along isn't the issue.  the spacing around the final plus sign in the first row is distracting, since there are many other plus signs in the same row.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do agree but I can't think of any way to improve this without contradicting at least one of the OP's wishes.

Comment: Besides, we can't know if the `+` signs of `c+e+n+t+e+r` are really meant as addition signs.

Comment: I don't think the spacing around the final plus sign in the first row is distracting, indeed, it's even what I wanted (or needed) as it makes clear that this `+` is the common element on all lines.

Comment: When using `array` can you still get equation numbers (that can be labeled) ?

Comment: @TomVerhoeff No, as far as I know.